# Laravel 5.6 Blade Page Loading Spinner

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have completed a project in laravel 5.6. However the only thing thats missing is the loading animation spinner when switching between pages which makes the UI look better and user understand that things are loading.

I have a loading.gif image in the public directory which i want to use in between page loads. I couldn't find any tutorial or helpful resources on this.

Could anyone tell me what is the easiest way to implement this as i need to get the project to production

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way for it is that just return a view in your controllers without any database connection and passing variables. then you can make an ajax call when page loaded to get data from the server. when ajax sent and Not answered yet you can show your loading gif. the controller should be like:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    if ($request->ajax()) {
      // calculations and queries here
    }

    return view('index');
}
```

but the better way is to use client-side frameworks like VueJS or AngularJS

Answer (score 5):

Place this code in your layout file (ex. app.blade.php) so It can be accessible throughout the system.

```
<div class="whole-page-overlay" id="whole_page_loader">
<img class="center-loader"  style="height:100px;" src="https://example.com/images/loader.gif"/>
```

CSS

```
.whole-page-overlay{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
}
.whole-page-overlay .center-loader{
  top: 50%;
  left: 52%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}
```

This will cover your entire page, now you can hide/show the div using #whole_page_loader selector.